# Execute npm with ant

Tags: npm, ant

I want to automate the build of an application with frontend and backend. To do this I want to use maven with ant for platform independent copy and cli tasks. With some cli's like `docker ...` this works. But this does not work for cli's provided by `npm` or `npm` itself.

```
<exec executable="docker">
    <arg line="version"/>
</exec>
<!--Works-->
<exec executable="C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd">
    <arg line="version"/>
</exec>
<!--Doesn't work-->
<exec executable="npm">
    <arg line="version"/>
</exec>
```

As seen in the second example, the script works if I specify the full path to the npm.cmd. But this should work at least on windows and unix. So specifying the full path is not an option.

Is there any way to run `npm` and its modules from ant?

---

**Late edit:**

The real problem was, that the windows node installer also placed a file named `npm` into the bin folder which is a bash script meant for cygwin. The npm bin folder was added to the 'global' `PATH` env var and the windows cmd did pick up the correct binary because it uses the `PATHEXT` env var to determine what is executable and what not. The ant exec plugin does not use `PATHEXT` and just executes the first file named `npm` which fails. The **Solution** was to rename the plain `npm` file in the path. This way ant sees the `npm.cmd` file first and everything runs smoothly.

Comment: For npm you should look for the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) which supports npm etc.

Comment: This fixed my problem. If you write an answer i will gladly accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you like to use npm you should take a look at the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

Comment: sorry but I think the context here is ant not maven

Comment: Than you shouldn't have marked it with tag `maven`. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old, but this is what I have, for others in the future. Works in our mac, unix, and windows boxes.

```
  <macrodef name="exec-node">
    <attribute name="module" description="The name of the NodeJS module to execute" />
    <attribute name="failonerror" default="true" description="Fail if the exit code is not 0" />
    <attribute name="dir" description="Directory to execute task" />
    <element name="args" implicit="yes" description="Argument to pass to the exec task" />
    <sequential>
      <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="@{dir}" failonerror="@{failonerror}" osfamily="winnt">
        <arg line="/c  @{module}" />
        <args />
      </exec>
      <exec executable="@{module}" dir="@{dir}" failonerror="@{failonerror}" osfamily="unix" logError="true">
        <args />
      </exec>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>
```

Then things like this can work

```
    <exec-node dir="${node.project.dir}" module="npm" failonerror="true" >
      <arg value="run" />
      <arg value="lint" />
    </exec-node>
```

You can of course hardcode module as npm, or default it, but I use this with npm and npx.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, its not possible to call npm directly through the antrun plugin.

I did manage to get it tu run by calling cmd (on windows) with the /c argument.

Example:

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg line="/c npm run babel -- src/main/webapp/js/es6/ --presets babel-preset-es2015 --out-dir src/main/webapp/js/"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: how about in mac?

Comment: This is a fairly old answer, at this point I'd recommend against it and instead would use exec-maven-plugin to just call scripts defined in your package.json

Comment: I am sorry but ant is the only option for this project for now.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Windows:

```
<exec executable="npm.cmd">
    <arg value="version"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution had to run on unix and windows, so refering to `npm.cmd` is not a solution. I added the used solution to the question.

Comment: You can add an osfamily as in @jaime-garza's answer.